# How do I properly add a return character to this script?

Tags: bash, gruntjs, npm, jshint

Here is a script I use to run grunt "globally".  It is in a bash shell and SO wants more context so I wan the return character so that it is a bit more "silent" when I run `beast watch`.

```
beast() {
  cd ~/root_install/grunt
  local a="$1"
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
     grunt &
  fi
  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
      grunt "$a" &
  fi
  cd ~/root
}
```

I want a return character at this part:

```
  grunt "$a" &
```

after the &

Comment: Much simpler to just use `grunt "$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run grunt you will get one of the exit codes below.

- 0 - No errors!
- 1 - Fatal error
- 2 - Missing gruntfile error
- 3 - Task error
- 4 - Template processing error
- 5 - Invalid shell auto-completion rules error
- 6 - Warning

What you can do is grab it like `grunt "$a" &>/dev/null` then pick result using `$?`

So you can do `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` like controls on return code.

`&>/dev/null` This is just an abbreviation for 2>&1

It redirects file descriptor 2 and 1 (STDERR & STDOUT) to /dev/null

Comment: What is &>/dev/null ... can you break it down ?

Comment: added more explanation to answer.

Comment: you never mentioned how this is a return character.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make a returnvalue, assign the returnvalue `$?` to it:

```
   grunt "$a" > grunt.log 2>&1
   returnvalue=$?
```

You can change grunt.log to /dev/null. 
After `cd ~/root` you can `return ${returnvalue}`.
When you want grunt to run in the background, you can change the line into

```
nohup grunt "$a" > grunt.log 2>&1 &
```

This will give you a new challenge: When starting in the background succeeds and grunt fails in 2 seconds, your $? returnvalue will not notice this.
How to handle this?
When the returnvalue is 0, wait for some time (20 seconds?) and check the logfile.